# Swift - Difference between passing variable and passing variable address withUnsafePointer?

Tags: ios, swift

recently I was trying to see the address of my variable and I have this question.

```
var age: Int = 5

withUnsafePointer(to: age) {
    print($0) // 0x00007ffee3362750
    print($0.pointee) // 5
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &age) {
    print($0) // 0x000000010d226330
    print($0.pointee) // 5
}
```

why it shows different memory address and why it shows the same value for the `pointee`?

```
var strarr = [1, 2]

withUnsafePointer(to: strarr[0]) {
    print("\($0)") // 0x00007ffee3362750
    print("\($0.pointee)") // 1
}

withUnsafePointer(to: strarr[1]) {
    print("\($0)") // 0x00007ffee3362750
    print("\($0.pointee)") // 2
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &strarr[0]) {
    print("\($0)") // 0x0000600002755760
    print("\($0.pointee)") // 1
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &strarr[1]) {
    print("\($0)") // 0x0000600002755768
    print("\($0.pointee)") // 2
}
```

for the array, why it shows the same memory address for index 1 and 2, when I'm not passing the address of the variable and why it shows a different memory address for index 1 and 2 when I'm passing the memory address?

Appreciate your answer and looking forward to understand this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The differences you see come from the fact that you are using two different overloads of `withUnsafePointer`, I'll list them in the same order you used them:

```swift
func withUnsafePointer<T, Result>(to value: T, _ body: (UnsafePointer<T>) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

, and

```swift
func withUnsafePointer<T, Result>(to value: inout T, _ body: (UnsafePointer<T>) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

The difference between the two is the `inout` qualifier used for the `value` parameter.

Now, let's try to understand what happens behind the scenes.

First, `0x00007ffee3362750` looks like a stack pointer, while `0x000000010d226330` looks like a heap pointer. Stack addresses start at the top of the allocated memory for the program, and decrease with every function call (and increase when the function returns).

This indicates that the first overload of `withUnsafePointer` create a temporary writable variable from the one passed as the argument. This is needed as `UnsafePointer` needs an `inout` reference to work with, and a regular parameter is readonly.

This means that the implementation of the non-inout overload of `withUnsafePointer` looks something like this:

```swift
func withUnsafePointer<T, Result>(to value: T, _ body: (UnsafePointer<T>) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result {
    var value = value // shadow the argument, create a readwrite location
    return try withUnsafePointer(&value, body)
}
```

Thus, the first call needs to allocate an intermediate memory location, and this is why you see two different addresses, it's because the addresses are not pointing to the same memory location. However, since both memory locations start with the same value, printing the `pointee` results in identical output.

---

Now, let's talk about the array example. The behaviour you see has the same cause: stack allocations. What happens is:

1. program starts executing, stack pointer has value P (random name)
2. non-inout `withUnsafePointer` is called, this is a function call, and stack is reserved for the function; stack pointer is P - N
3. `withUnsafePointer` creates the temporary writable variable, and executes
4. `withUnsafePointer` returns, and frees the stack memory, at this stack pointer gets back to P
5. second non-inout `withUnsafePointer` is called, the stack pointer is back to P - N, however since there were no other function calls between the two, the same stack address is reserved for the temporary writable variable, thus the `UnsafePointer` instance has the same address

Here, even if the `UnsafePointer` points to the same address, the values at that address are different, corresponding to values of `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.

As for the inout calls, the `UnsafePointer` point to the actual addresses of the items in the array buffer.

This is how you can get different values for the non-inout calls too:

```swift
withUnsafePointer(to: strarr[0]) {
    print("\($0)")
    print("\($0.pointee)")
}

// this adds a nested function call, which also decreases the stack pointer
// resulting in the temporary location not being on the same stack address
func test() {
    withUnsafePointer(to: strarr[1]) {
        print("\($0)")
        print("\($0.pointee)")
    }
}
test()
```